# How to read XML file in groovy?

Tags: file, groovy, xmlslurper

I am trying to read XML file in groovy with below lines of code

```
def xml=new XmlSlurper().parse("C:\2011XmlLog20110524_0623")  
xml.Document.BillID.each{   
println it}
```

I am getting file not found error though i have the file in my C drive..is there any syntax mistake there?..

With advance thanks,

Laxmi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use any of:

- `"C:/2011XmlLog20110524_0623"`
- `"C:\\2011XmlLog20110524_0623"`

Backslash is an [escape character](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Comment: Hi can you please look at a similar [question here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278530/read-a-xml-file-in-groovy)