# How to import files while loading a groovy class?

Tags: groovy

I am loading a class and doing some sql select statements, it seems that `import groovy.sql.Sql` needs to be imported. How can I load some library while loading a class?

My code (works fine if I remove Sql operations)

```
def fClass = new GroovyClassLoader().parseClass( new File( 'plugin/Pi.groovy' ) )
result=fClass.newInstance().buildTags( params, i9piparams, "userRoleCount")
```

pi.groovy

```
public class Pi{
    def result

    private def getDbUrl(dbdriver,dbhost,dbport,dbname)
    {
        return "$dbdriver:@$dbhost:$dbport:$dbname"
    }

    public def buildTags(Map<String,String> params,Map<String,String> i9piparams,def i9piType)
    {

        println params
        println i9piparams

        /*some Sql operation*/
        Driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            dbdriver="jdbc:oracle:thin"
        def url=getDbUrl(dbdriver,params.tns,i9piparams.dbport,i9piparams.dbname)           

            def sql = Sql.newInstance(url,params.u,params.x,Driver)

            sql.eachRow("select name, value from v\$parameter where name = 'open_cursors'"){ row ->
                result.name=row.name
                result.value=row.value
            }

    }
}
```

Output

```
[pd:admin, u:zx5531d, tns:foner, dh:abds, dn:D35531, dp:11531, un:admin, x:cx15531]
[:, dbname:orcl, dbport:1521, dbtype:oracle]
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: groovy.sql.Sql(org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl, groovy.util.slurpersupport.Attributes, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try changing your line:

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance(url,params.u,params.x,Driver)
```

to

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance( url, 'zx5531d', params.x, Driver )
```

What I suspect is that you need to call `text()` on the attributes when you read them from the XML, so that you get a `String` rather than a `groovy.util.slurpersupport.Attributes` class.

Also, why has `Driver` got a capital initial letter?

And (not sure what `parameter` is), but you probably want to change:

```
"select name, value from v\$parameter where name = 'open_cursors'"
```

to

```
"select name, value from v\${Sql.expand(parameter)} where name = 'open_cursors'"
```

Comment: Hi, I made chages accordingly & it gave me `Invalid Url` here is my url `jdbc:oracle:thin:@foner:1521:orcl`. Also about Driver, I am refactoring a old code so missed it.

Comment: Do you have the oracle driver on the system classpath?

Comment: @AbhishekSimon PS:  I updated my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10278678/6509) to apply the `text()` call to each attribute call

Comment: I used `jdbc:oracle:thin://foner:1521;ServiceName=orcl` url and it worked. Whats the difference between these two urls here?

Comment: @AbhishekSimon Not sure...  as far as I can tell, they should be handled the same...  Not done Oracle for a good few years though :-/